# Como separar o ano de uma data com Python e Pandas?

Tags: python, data, pandas, split

Tenho uma base de dados de alunos com uma coluna de Data de Ingresso no formato dd/mm/aa.
Eu preciso gerar uma coluna Ano_Ingresso apenas com o ano da data de cada registro.

[image: Exemplo da base]

[image: Resultado esperado]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('alunos.csv', sep='|')
data = df['DT_INGRESSO']
data.str.split('/')
ano = data[2]
```

Tentei algo com o str.split(), que separa dia, mês e ano numa lista, mas não consegui pensar em uma forma de fazer isso para todos os registros. Sou iniciante em Python.

Comment: Acredito que você não tenha entendido como o pandas funciona, https://paulovasconcellos.com.br/28-comandos-%C3%BAteis-de-pandas-que-talvez-voc%C3%AA-n%C3%A3o-conhe%C3%A7a-6ab64beefa93

Comment: Sou iniciante em Python no geral. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro passo a coluna `DT_INGRESSO` para tipo `datetime` (e não mais string). Repare que as datas estão no format `dd/mm/aaaa`, então seu formato é `%d/%m/%Y`:

`df['DT_INGRESSO'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['DT_INGRESSO'], format='%d/%m/%Y')`

Depois pego o atributo `year` (ano) de cada data e armazeno em uma nova coluna `ANO`:

`df['ANO'] = df['DT_INGRESSO'].dt.year`

Comment: Deu certo convertendo para datetime. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Olha ainda não cheguei a usar pandas, mais se na sua variável `data` for uma lista com os dados da coluna. Tem um maneira fácil de obter apenas os anos das datas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('alunos.csv', sep='|')
data = df['DT_INGRESSO'] # se o resultado for uma lista das datas do banco
ano = [a.split('/')[-1] for a in data]
df['ANO_INGRESSO'] = ano
```